# ¿Como puedo guardar solamente el texto que contiene cierto checkbox en una base de datos

Tags: php, html

Pues la verdad se como hacerlo, pero si utilizo el atributo value. El problema está en que para otra función de un formulario, utilizo el value, y no puedo utilizar el mismo valor del value. Lo que quiero es que cuando el cliente oprima el checkbox, el trxto de este checkbox se guarde en una base de datos

Este es mi código HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>formulario</title>
      <link rel ="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="estilos.css">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      $(function(){
      $("input[type=radio]").add("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(){
        calcular();
      })

    });

    function calcular(){
      $radios = $("input[type=radio]:checked");
      $checkboxs = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
      var coste_total = 0;
      $checkboxs.each(function(){
        coste_total = coste_total + parseInt($(this).val());
      })
      $radios.each(function(){
        coste_total = coste_total + parseInt($(this).val());
      })
      $(".resultado").html(coste_total)
    }
    </script>
    <body>
      <div clas="wrap">
                <form action="insert.php" class="formulario" method="POST">
                  <br>
                  <p>BOOKS</p>
                  <div class="checkbox">
                  <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="20" id="CourseBooks" class="get_value" value="CourseBooks" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="CourseBooks">CourseBooks</label>

                    <input type="checkbox" value="20" id="PracticeBooks" class="get_value" value="PracticeBooks" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="PracticeBooks">PracticeBooks</label>
                  <br>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <p>CONCRETS</p>
                  <div class="radio">
                   <input value ="8" type="radio" id="All Suggested" value="first_radio" style="display: none;" required>
                   <label for="All Suggested">All Suggested</label>

                    <input value="4" type="radio" id="Some Suggested" value="second_radio" style="display: none;" required>
                    <label for="Some Suggested">Some Suggested</label>

                    <input value="0" type="radio" id="None Suggested" value="third_radio" style="display: none;" required>
                    <label for="None Suggested">None Suggested</label>

                  <br>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="text">
                  <p>TEACHERS</p>
                    <label for="Number of Teachers">Number of Teachers</label>
                    <input type="number" name="Number of Teachers" placeholder="number" required>
                  <br>
                    <label for="Number of Trained Teachers">Number of Trained Teachers</label>
                    <input type="number" name="Number of Trained Teachers" placeholder="number" required>
                  <br>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <p>TRAININGS</p>
                  <div class="radio">
                    <input value="4" type="radio" id="Module 1: Foundatons" style="display: none;" required>
                    <label for="Module 1: Foundatons">Module 1: Foundatons</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="radio" id="Module 2: Questioning" style="display: none;" required>
                    <label for="Module 2: Questioning">Module 2: Questioning</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="radio" id="Module 3: Smart Environments" style="display: none;" required>
                    <label for="Module 3: Smart Environments">Module 3: Smart Environments</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="radio" id="Module 4: Differentiation" style="display: none;" required>
                    <label for="Module 4: Differentiation">Module 4: Differentiation</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="radio" id="Module 5: Innovation" style="display: none;" required>
                    <label for="Module 5: Innovation">Module 5: Innovation</label>
                  <br>
                </div>
                  <br>
                  <P>CURRICULUM</P>
                  <br>
                  <div class="radio">
                  <p>Line Up</p>
                  <br>
                    <input value="4" type="radio" id="90%-100%"  style="display: none;" required>
                    <label for="90%-100%">90% - 100%</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="3" type="radio" id="80%-89%" style="display: none;" required>
                    <label for="80%-89%">80% - 89%</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="radio" id="70%-79%" style="display: none;" required>
                    <label for="70%-79%">70% - 79%</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="1" type="radio" id="Less than 70%" style="display: none;" required>
                    <label for="Less than 70%">Less than 70%</label>
                  <br>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <p>CLASS OBSERVATIONS</p>
                  <div class="radio">
                  <br>
                    <input value="1" type="radio" id="One Routine" style="display: none;" >
                    <label for="One Routine">One Routine</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="radio" id="Two Routines" style="display: none;" >
                    <label for="Two Routines">Two Routines</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="3" type="radio" id="Three Routines" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Three Routines">Three Routines</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="4" type="radio" id="Four Routines"  style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Four Routines">Four Routines</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="5" type="radio" id="Five Routines"  style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Five Routines">Five Routines</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="6" type="radio" id="Six Routines"  style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Six Routines">Six Routines</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="7" type="radio" id="Seven Routines"  style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Seven Routines">Seven Routines</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="8" type="radio" id="Eight Routines" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Eight Routines">Eight Routines</label>
                  <br>
                </div>
                  <br>
                  <p>INTERVENTIONS</p>
                  <div class="checkbox">
                  <br>
                    <input value="8" type="checkbox" id="Still learning Students protocolo" value="Still learning Students protocolo" name="checkboxs[]" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Still learning Students protocolo">Still learning Students protocolo</label>
                  <br>
                </div>
                  <br>
                  <p>TESTING</p>
                  <div class="checkbox">
                  <p>Pre-post testing</p>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="One Grade"  name="checkboxs[]" value="One Grade" style="display: none;" >
                    <label for="One Grade">One Grade</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="Two Grades"  name="checkboxs[]" value="Two Grades" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Two Grades">Two Grades</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="Three Grades"  name="checkboxs[]" value="Three Grades" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Three Grades">Three Grades</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="Four Grades"  name="checkboxs[]" value="Four Grades" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Four Grades">Four Grades</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="Five Grades"  name="checkboxs[]" value="Five Grades" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Five Grades">Five Grades</label>
                  <br>
                    <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="Six Grades"  name="checkboxs[]" value="Six Grades" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="Six Grades">Six Grades</label>
                  <br>
                </div>
                  <br>
                  <p style="color:#0774D9; font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Verdana' ">Implementation Quality</p>
                  <p  class="resultado" style="background:#0774D9; color: #fff; font-size: 30px"></p>

                  <br>

                  <div class="text">

                    <label for="Teachers_Name">Teacher's Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Teachers_Name" id="Teachers_Name" placeholder="Name" required>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                    <label for="School_Name">School Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="School_Name" id="School_Name" placeholder="School Name" required>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                    <label for="Implementation_Quality">Write here your Implementation Quality score :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Implementation_Quality" id="Implementation_Quality" placeholder="Implementation Quality" required>

                  </div>
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 20px;background:#0774D9; color: #fff; font-size: 20px; border-radius: 10px; font-family: 'Verdana';padding: 5px 15px 5px 20px; text-align: center; ">

                </form>
      </div>
      <h1 id="result"></h1>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
      var insert = [];
      $('.get_value').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
          insert.push($(this).val())
        }
      });
      insert = insert.toString();
      $.ajax({
        url:"insert.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:(insert:insert),
        success:function(data){
          $('#result').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");

    if(!$conexion){
    echo "Conexión no exitosa";
     } else {

    $base= mysqli_select_db($conexion, "datos1");
        if(!$base){
            echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos";
        }
    }
    //LLAMAMOS LAS VARIBALES
    $checkbox= isset($_POST['insert']);
    $query= "INSERT INTO BOOKS(name) () VALUES('".$_POST["insert"]."') ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $Teachers_Name="";
    $Teachers_Name= isset($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name']:'';
    $Teachers_Name= empty($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name']:'';
    $Teachers_Name= $_POST['Teachers_Name'] ?? '';
    $School_Name="";
    $School_Name= isset($_POST['School_Name']) ? $_POST['School_Name']:'';
    $School_Name= empty($_POST['School_Name']) ? $_POST['School_Name']:'';
    $School_Name= $_POST['School_Name'] ?? '';
    $Implementation_Quality= "";
    $Implementation_Quality= isset($_POST['Implementation_Quality']) ? 
    $_POST['Implementation_Quality']:'';
    $Implementation_Quality= empty($_POST['Implementation_Quality']) ? 
    $_POST['Implementation_Quality']:'';
    $Implementation_Quality= $_POST['Implementation_Quality'] ?? '';
    //Guarda las variables


    $sql= "INSERT INTO datos_1 (Teachers_Name, School_Name, 
    Implementation_Quality) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

    $sth = mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'sss', $Teachers_Name, $School_Name, 
    $Implementation_Quality);
    $ejecutar = mysqli_stmt_execute($sth);

    if(!$ejecutar){
     echo "Hubo algun error";
    } else {
     echo "Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='index.php'>Volver</a>";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar un poco más lo que quieres obtener y lo que estás obteniendo? Actualmente no queda muy claro. Intenta simplificar un poco más tu código para poder focalizar mucho mejor en el problema. Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Pues en verdad lo que quiero es que cuando el cliente haga click en un checkbox, el texto del checkbox se guarde en la base de datos. Solo ayudenme con este caso de aquí, para luego tener idea de que hacer

HTML

```
<form action="insert.php" class="formulario" method="POST">
              <br>
              <p>BOOKS</p>
              <div class="checkbox">
              <br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="20" id="CourseBooks" class="get_value" value="CourseBooks" style="display: none;">
                <label for="CourseBooks">CourseBooks</label>

                <input type="checkbox" value="20" id="PracticeBooks" class="get_value" value="PracticeBooks" style="display: none;">
                <label for="PracticeBooks">PracticeBooks</label>
              <br>
              </div>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" 
               style="margin-left: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 
               20px;background:#0774D9; color: #fff; font-size: 20px; 
               border-radius: 10px; font-family: 'Verdana';padding: 5px 15px 
               5px 20px; text-align: center; ">
```

Javascript

```
<script>

  $(function(){
  $("input[type=radio]").add("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(){
    calcular();
  })

});

function calcular(){
  $radios = $("input[type=radio]:checked");
  $checkboxs = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  var coste_total = 0;
  $checkboxs.each(function(){
    coste_total = coste_total + parseInt($(this).val());
  })
  $radios.each(function(){
    coste_total = coste_total + parseInt($(this).val());
  })
  $(".resultado").html(coste_total)
}
```

Jquery

```
<h1 id="result"></h1>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#submit').click(function(){
   var insert = [];
   $('.get_value').each(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked"))
     {
       insert.push($(this).val())
     }
   });
   insert = insert.toString();
   $.ajax({
     url:"insert.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:(insert:insert),
     success:function(data){
       $('#result').html(data);
    }
  });
});
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
 $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");

 if(!$conexion){
 echo "Conexión no exitosa";
 } else {

 $base= mysqli_select_db($conexion, "datos1");
    if(!$base){
        echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos";
    }
 }
//LLAMAMOS LAS VARIBALES
 $checkbox= isset($_POST['insert']);
 $query= "INSERT INTO BOOKS(name) () VALUES('".$_POST["insert"]."') ";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 $Teachers_Name="";
 $Teachers_Name= isset($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name']:'';
 $Teachers_Name= empty($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name']:'';
 $Teachers_Name= $_POST['Teachers_Name'] ?? '';
 $School_Name="";
 $School_Name= isset($_POST['School_Name']) ? $_POST['School_Name']:'';
 $School_Name= empty($_POST['School_Name']) ? $_POST['School_Name']:'';
 $School_Name= $_POST['School_Name'] ?? '';
 $Implementation_Quality= "";
 $Implementation_Quality= isset($_POST['Implementation_Quality']) ? $_POST['Implementation_Quality']:'';
 $Implementation_Quality= empty($_POST['Implementation_Quality']) ? $_POST['Implementation_Quality']:'';
 $Implementation_Quality= $_POST['Implementation_Quality'] ?? '';
 //Guarda las variables


 $sql= "INSERT INTO datos_1 (Teachers_Name, School_Name, 
  Implementation_Quality) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

 $sth = mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'sss', $Teachers_Name, $School_Name, 
 $Implementation_Quality);
 $ejecutar = mysqli_stmt_execute($sth);

 if(!$ejecutar){
    echo "Hubo algun error";
 } else {
    echo "Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='index.php'>Volver</a>";
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Tus checkbox tienen dos atributos `value`. Aparte de eso, si quieres recibir un texto distinto al marcar un checkbox podrías hacerlo con Javascript, por ejemplo asociando el valor de un `input hidden`a los eventos de los checkbox (`onclick`o similar).

Comment: Pero si pongo el hidden, y presiona el otro checkbox, igual toma el valor de el hidden?

Comment: O mejor dicho como asocio el valor de un input hidden, con el de un checkbox?

Comment: Si has de enviar varios checkbox... un hidden por checkbox; en caso de optar por esa estrategia.
Con asociar me refería a que asocies un evento del checkbox (como `onclick`) que te permita cambiar el valor del hidden cuando se active el checkbox; por ejemplo.

Comment: Pues he estado haciendo esto pero no se como hacer que me cambie el valor del value, por el de el otro value : insert.push($(this).attr("attribute","other atribute","value"));